# How to stop appengine from creating automated multiple default queue?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, multi-tenant, task-queue

I have not written any code which creates taskqueue in application. still while running application multiple queues are generated in backgraound.

This application is Multitenant application and `NamespaceManager.set()` is called before performing DAO commands like `getObjectById`, `makePersistent`.

Taskqueue on dashboard-

```
Name    ETA Creation Time   Method/URL  Retries Executions  Payload Actions
```

12914588931600734283
↓
2014/06/24 21:41:34
0:01:00 ago  2014/06/24 21:41:34
0:01:01 ago  POST /_ah/queue/**deferred**            1116 bytes
6 Headers   Run Now

2741788704643718514
↓
2014/06/24 21:40:44
0:01:51 ago  2014/06/24 21:40:44
0:01:51 ago  POST /_ah/queue/**deferred**            892 bytes
6 Headers   Run Now

5571553031267592814
↓
2014/06/24 21:41:33
0:01:02 ago  2014/06/24 21:41:33
0:01:02 ago  POST /_ah/queue/**deferred**            1041 bytes
6 Headers   Run Now

9741325715271053513
↓
2014/06/24 21:40:58
0:01:37 ago  2014/06/24 21:40:58
0:01:37 ago  POST /_ah/queue/**deferred**            892 bytes
6 Headers   Run Now

9741325715271056707
↓
2014/06/24 21:41:34
0:01:01 ago  2014/06/24 21:41:34
0:01:01 ago  POST /_ah/queue/**deferred**            1113 bytes
6 Headers   Run Now

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/NamespaceManager), **NamespaceManager.set()** uses **Queue.add()** internally. This is probably done using a [DeferredTask](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/DeferredTask), which is what is creating the **deferred** queue shown in your logs.